# HTML/JS | Email JS Error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email, onclick

I am using HTML/CSS/JS & Email JS in my Contact Us code and this is the full error it displays below; Please note that the Contact Us form is both validating and sending an email using Email JS when clicked.

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

How I reached this error was I was trying to use two **onclicks** in the Contact submit form button which I solved by using the code below;

```
    <div class="col-md-6 animate" data-animate="fadeInUp">
        <form id="ajax-contact" name="mydata" action="/index.html" method="POST">
            <div class="input-field">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"
                    placeholder="Name">
                <div class="error" id="name_err"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
                    placeholder="Email">
                <div class="error" id="email_err"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message"
                    placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <div class="error" id="message_err"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn" type="submit" onclick="submitForm(event)">Submit
            </button>
        </form>
        <!-- <div id="form-messages" class="mt-3"></div> -->
    </div>
```

Please note that even if I removed the **event** on the **onclick** like onclick="submitForm()" it still doesn't send the email.

Below is my validation code the file is called validateContact.js and I combined the send Email using Email JS code in one file as below:

```
function printError(elemId, hintMsg){
    document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML = hintMsg;
}

function contactUs(){ 
    var name = document.mydata.name.value;
    var email = document.mydata.email.value;
    var message = document.mydata.message.value;
    
    // ___ Defining error variables with default value
    var name_err = email_err = message_err = true;

    // _______ validating Name
    if(name === ""){
        printError("name_err", "Please Enter Your Name");
        const errId = document.getElementById('name');
        errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
    }
    else  if(name.length < 5 || name.length > 50){
        printError("name_err", "Names should be between 5-50 characters");
        const errId = document.getElementById('name');
        errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
    }
    else{
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
        if(regex.test(name) === false){
            printError("name_err", "Names should not include numeral characters.");
            const errId = document.getElementById('name');
            errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
        }else{
            var uppercase = /^[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*/;
            if(uppercase.test(name) === false){
            printError("name_err", "First letter of Name should be In Uppercase i.e Phil Ubuntu");
            const errId = document.getElementById('name');
            errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
        }else{
            printError("name_err", "");
            name_err = false;
        }
        }
    }

    // _______ validating Email Info
    if(email === ""){
        printError("email_err", "Email cannot be left Empty");
        const errId = document.getElementById('email');
        errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
    }else{
        var letters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;;
        if(letters.test(email) === false){
            printError("email_err", "Invalid Email(Include @)")
            const errId = document.getElementById('email');
            errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
        }else{
            printError("email_err", "");
            email_err = false;
        }
    }

    // _______ validating message
    if(message === ""){
        printError("message_err", "Please Enter Your Message");
        const errId = document.getElementById('message');
        errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
        }    else{
            var uppercase = /^[A-Z][a-z]*/;
            if(uppercase.test(message) === false){
                printError("message_err", "First letter Should be In CapsLock e.g This is..");
                const errId = document.getElementById('message');
                errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
            }else{
            printError("message_err", "");
            message_err = false;
        }
    }

    // // __Preventing the form from being submited if their are any errors
    // if(( name_err || email_err || message_err) === true){
    //     // Temporary removing this as suggested by ChatGPT when calling 2 function on submit button
    //     // we removed the event.preventDefault don't use this code in other project.
    //     // event.preventDefault()
    // }else{
    //     event.currentTarget.submit()
    // }  
}

    // Send Email      
    function sendMail() {
        var params = {
          name: document.getElementById("name").value,
          email: document.getElementById("email").value,
          message: document.getElementById("message").value,
        };
      
        const serviceID = "service_0vlh0ul";
        const templateID = "template_9n4gyyb";
      
          emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, params)
          .then(res=>{
              document.getElementById("name").value = "";
              document.getElementById("email").value = "";
              document.getElementById("message").value = "";
              console.log(res);
              alert("Your message sent successfully!!")
      
          })
          .catch(err=>console.log(err));
      }

    // async function sendMail() {
    //     var params = {
    //       name: document.getElementById("name").value,
    //       email: document.getElementById("email").value,
    //       message: document.getElementById("message").value,
    //     };
      
    //     const serviceID = "service_0vlh0ul"; // Replace with your EmailJS service ID
    //     const templateID = "template_9n4gyyb"; // Replace with your EmailJS template ID
      
    //     try {
    //       const result = await emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, params);
    //       console.log(result);
    //       alert("Your message sent successfully!!");
    //       // Clear the form fields after successful submission
    //       document.getElementById("name").value = "";
    //       document.getElementById("email").value = "";
    //       document.getElementById("message").value = "";
    //     } catch (error) {
    //       console.error("Error sending email:", error);
    //     }
    //   }

      function submitForm() {
        // Call contactUs() first to perform validation
        contactUs();

          // Prevent the default form submission
        event.preventDefault();
      
        // Check if the validation was successful before proceeding with sending email
        if (!name_err && !email_err && !message_err) {
          // If validation passes, call the sendMail() function to submit the form data via emailJS
          sendMail();
        } else {
          // If there are validation errors, do nothing. The form will not submit.
        }
      }
```

Please Note that in my **index.js** file i have Email.JS scripts in my header tag as below:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/validateContact.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@emailjs/browser@3/dist/email.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            emailjs.init("NMjjGTpQTLxIksxsp");
        })();
    </script>
</head>
```

Now I tried solving the **Uncaught In Promise Error** since ChatGPT told me it was caused by  as displayed below but its still not sending the email:

> The error message "Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated
> an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel
> closed before a response was received" is related to a known issue
> with the emailjs-com library. This issue can occur if there is a race
> condition between the emailjs-com library and the form submission,
> leading to the message channel closing before a response is received
> from EmailJS.
>
> To fix this issue, you can use the older version of the emailjs-com
> library (v2.6.4) since it doesn't have this particular problem. Here's
> how you can include the correct version in your HTML file:
>
> html Copy code
>
> ```
> <script src="https://cdn.emailjs.com/dist/email.min.js"></script>
> Ensure that you are including the version 2.6.4 of the emailjs-com library, as newer versions may still have the issue.
> ```
>
> Additionally, to prevent any other potential race conditions, you can
> modify the sendMail() function to use the async/await syntax. This
> will ensure that the promise is resolved before proceeding further.
> Here's the updated sendMail() function:
>
> javascript Copy code
>
> ```
> async function sendMail() {
>   var params = {
>     name: document.getElementById("name").value,
>     email: document.getElementById("email").value,
>     message: document.getElementById("message").value,
>   };
>
>   const serviceID = "YOUR_EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID"; // Replace with your EmailJS service ID
>   const templateID = "YOUR_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID"; // Replace with your EmailJS template ID
>
>   try {
>     const result = await emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, params);
>     console.log(result);
>     alert("Your message sent successfully!!");
>     // Clear the form fields after successful submission
>     document.getElementById("name").value = "";
>     document.getElementById("email").value = "";
>     document.getElementById("message").value = "";
>   } catch (error) {
>     console.error("Error sending email:", error);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> With these changes, the race condition issue should be resolved, and
> the sendMail() function should work correctly without throwing the
> mentioned error. The email should be sent successfully after the form
> validation passes.
>
> Please note that using the older version of the library is a temporary
> workaround until the issue is fixed in the newer versions. Be sure to
> keep an eye on the emailjs-com library updates for any improvements or
> fixes in future versions.

Please note that before **validate.js** and **email.js** files before i combined them into one onclick, **onclick="submitForm(event)"** were working correctly.

Surprisingly! now after reverting the code and not using the async await & going back to my original code it now doesn't show any errors as of screenshot below, the errors their are of something else please ignore them unless i have confused them but as of now you can see their is no **"Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received"**:
[image: Console No Email.JS Uncaught Promise Error]

I am going to send the original **validate.js** and original **email.js** files before i combined and made changes to the code so they could work on a single onclick.

validate.js file original

```
    function printError(elemId, hintMsg){
        document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML = hintMsg;
    }
    
    function contactUs(){ 
        var name = document.mydata.name.value;
        var email = document.mydata.email.value;
        var message = document.mydata.message.value;
        
        // ___ Defining error variables with default value
        var name_err = email_err = message_err = true;
    
        // _______ validating Name
        if(name === ""){
            printError("name_err", "Please Enter Your Name");
            const errId = document.getElementById('name');
            errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
        }
        else  if(name.length < 5 || name.length > 50){
            printError("name_err", "Names should be between 5-50 characters");
            const errId = document.getElementById('name');
            errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
        }
        else{
            var regex = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
            if(regex.test(name) === false){
                printError("name_err", "Names should not include numeral characters.");
                const errId = document.getElementById('name');
                errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
            }else{
                var uppercase = /^[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*/;
                if(uppercase.test(name) === false){
                printError("name_err", "First letter of Name should be In Uppercase i.e Phil Ubuntu");
                const errId = document.getElementById('name');
                errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
            }else{
                printError("name_err", "");
                name_err = false;
            }
            }
        }
    
        // _______ validating Email Info
        if(email === ""){
            printError("email_err", "Email cannot be left Empty");
            const errId = document.getElementById('email');
            errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
        }else{
            var letters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;;
            if(letters.test(email) === false){
                printError("email_err", "Invalid Email(Include @)")
                const errId = document.getElementById('email');
                errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
            }else{
                printError("email_err", "");
                email_err = false;
            }
        }
    
        // _______ validating message
        if(message === ""){
            printError("message_err", "Please Enter Your Message");
            const errId = document.getElementById('message');
            errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
            }    else{
                var uppercase = /^[A-Z][a-z]*/;
                if(uppercase.test(message) === false){
                    printError("message_err", "First letter Should be In CapsLock e.g This is..");
                    const errId = document.getElementById('message');
                    errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
                }else{
                printError("message_err", "");
                message_err = false;
            }
        }
    
        // __Preventing the form from being submited if their are any errors
        if(( name_err || email_err || message_err) === true){
            // Temporary removing this as suggested by ChatGPT when calling 2 function on submit button
            // we removed the event.preventDefault don't use this code in other project.
            event.preventDefault()
        }else{
            event.currentTarget.submit()
        }  
    }

As you can see later on i removed the **event.preventDefault()** so the form could submit because i handled form handling using another function as am going to display later on below after showing you the original email.js code.

Original **email.js** code file before putting it under one onclick.
// // Send Email      
  function sendMail() {
    var params = {
      name: document.getElementById("name").value,
      email: document.getElementById("email").value,
      message: document.getElementById("message").value,
    };
  
    const serviceID = "service_0vlh0ul";
    const templateID = "template_9n4gyyb";
  
      emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, params)
      .then(res=>{
          document.getElementById("name").value = "";
          document.getElementById("email").value = "";
          document.getElementById("message").value = "";
          console.log(res);
          alert("Your message sent successfully!!")
  
      })
      .catch(err=>console.log(err));
  
  }

So as already posted above I said i combined the validate.js file and email.js file putting the code inside the validate.js file as currently looking below: This is my current running code as of now:

Combined validate.js and email.js code.
function printError(elemId, hintMsg){
    document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML = hintMsg;
}

function contactUs(){ 
    var name = document.mydata.name.value;
    var email = document.mydata.email.value;
    var message = document.mydata.message.value;
    
    // ___ Defining error variables with default value
    var name_err = email_err = message_err = true;

    // _______ validating Name
    if(name === ""){
        printError("name_err", "Please Enter Your Name");
        const errId = document.getElementById('name');
        errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
    }
    else  if(name.length < 5 || name.length > 50){
        printError("name_err", "Names should be between 5-50 characters");
        const errId = document.getElementById('name');
        errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
    }
    else{
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
        if(regex.test(name) === false){
            printError("name_err", "Names should not include numeral characters.");
            const errId = document.getElementById('name');
            errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
        }else{
            var uppercase = /^[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*/;
            if(uppercase.test(name) === false){
            printError("name_err", "First letter of Name should be In Uppercase i.e Phil Ubuntu");
            const errId = document.getElementById('name');
            errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
        }else{
            printError("name_err", "");
            name_err = false;
        }
        }
    }

    // _______ validating Email Info
    if(email === ""){
        printError("email_err", "Email cannot be left Empty");
        const errId = document.getElementById('email');
        errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
    }else{
        var letters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;;
        if(letters.test(email) === false){
            printError("email_err", "Invalid Email(Include @)")
            const errId = document.getElementById('email');
            errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
        }else{
            printError("email_err", "");
            email_err = false;
        }
    }

    // _______ validating message
    if(message === ""){
        printError("message_err", "Please Enter Your Message");
        const errId = document.getElementById('message');
        errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
        }    else{
            var uppercase = /^[A-Z][a-z]*/;
            if(uppercase.test(message) === false){
                printError("message_err", "First letter Should be In CapsLock e.g This is..");
                const errId = document.getElementById('message');
                errId.style.border = '1px solid red';
            }else{
            printError("message_err", "");
            message_err = false;
        }
    }

    // // __Preventing the form from being submited if their are any errors
    // if(( name_err || email_err || message_err) === true){
    //     // Temporary removing this as suggested by ChatGPT when calling 2 function on submit button
    //     // we removed the event.preventDefault don't use this code in other project.
    //     // event.preventDefault()
    // }else{
    //     event.currentTarget.submit()
    // }  
}

    // Send Email      
    function sendMail() {
        var params = {
          name: document.getElementById("name").value,
          email: document.getElementById("email").value,
          message: document.getElementById("message").value,
        };
      
        const serviceID = "service_0vlh0ul";
        const templateID = "template_9n4gyyb";
      
          emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, params)
          .then(res=>{
              document.getElementById("name").value = "";
              document.getElementById("email").value = "";
              document.getElementById("message").value = "";
              console.log(res);
              alert("Your message sent successfully!!")
      
          })
          .catch(err=>console.log(err));
      }

    // async function sendMail() {
    //     var params = {
    //       name: document.getElementById("name").value,
    //       email: document.getElementById("email").value,
    //       message: document.getElementById("message").value,
    //     };
      
    //     const serviceID = "service_0vlh0ul"; // Replace with your EmailJS service ID
    //     const templateID = "template_9n4gyyb"; // Replace with your EmailJS template ID
      
    //     try {
    //       const result = await emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, params);
    //       console.log(result);
    //       alert("Your message sent successfully!!");
    //       // Clear the form fields after successful submission
    //       document.getElementById("name").value = "";
    //       document.getElementById("email").value = "";
    //       document.getElementById("message").value = "";
    //     } catch (error) {
    //       console.error("Error sending email:", error);
    //     }
    //   }

      function submitForm() {
        // Call contactUs() first to perform validation
        contactUs();

          // Prevent the default form submission
        event.preventDefault();
      
        // Check if the validation was successful before proceeding with sending email
        if (!name_err && !email_err && !message_err) {
          // If validation passes, call the sendMail() function to submit the form data via emailJS
          sendMail();
        } else {
          // If there are validation errors, do nothing. The form will not submit.
        }
      }
```

As i said earlier when i removed the **event.preventDefault()** from here and updated it when i was handling form handling as am going to paste the code after this.

```
// // __Preventing the form from being submited if their are any errors
// if(( name_err || email_err || message_err) === true){
//     // Temporary removing this as suggested by ChatGPT when calling 2 function on submit button
//     // we removed the event.preventDefault don't use this code in other project.
//     // event.preventDefault()
// }else{
//     event.currentTarget.submit()
// }
```

I used the **event.preventDefault()** in the **submitForm()** function as below as this was handling form submission.

```
  function submitForm() {
    // Call contactUs() first to perform validation
    contactUs();

      // Prevent the default form submission
    event.preventDefault();
  
    // Check if the validation was successful before proceeding with sending email
    if (!name_err && !email_err && !message_err) {
      // If validation passes, call the sendMail() function to submit the form data via emailJS
      sendMail();
    } else {
      // If there are validation errors, do nothing. The form will not submit.
    }
  }
```

Now I am going to show you my current **index.html** code file, please ensure to scroll till below so you can find the contact section as all the pages of the **Portfolio website** are on the **index.js file**.
Due to StackOverflow limit to 30000 characters i have removed the index.html file hope this helps